# If $f'$ is continuous at the point $x_0$, does this imply $f$ is Lipschitz around $x_0$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let $f : R^n \to R^m $ which is differentiable around the point $x_0$, whose derivative is continuous at the point $x_0$. Does this imply $f$ is Lipschitz around $x_0$

My intuition:  Since $f'$ is continuous at the point $x_0$, this shows $f'$ is bounded around $x_0$ this somehow is tempting me that $f$ has to be Lipschitz.

Any proof or counter-example?

Thank You

Comment: Have you tried anything? Do you have any reasons or intuitions to believe the proposition or its negation?

Comment: @Red shoes: This may help. http://mathonline.wikidot.com/corollaries-to-the-mean-value-theorem-for-differentiable-fun

Comment: @YadatiKiran Thank You .  But in your link , in relation 6 , the second line doesn't seem correct . ?  

or I guess we could take an especial $a$

Comment: @Redshoes: Thats because they have chosen $a\in\mathbb{R}^m$ such that $||a||=1$.

Comment: It has nothing to do with norm . they are literally saying $| a.b  | = \|a\|  \|b\|$